# Why doesn't my statement to disable form submission work?

Tags: javascript

I have a checkout form on my website that uses a custom validation method implemented with Bootstrap. It has a JavaScript function to prevent the form from being submitted multiple times if it is filled out correctly. I'm using a technique commonly suggested on SO to disable the submission, albeit with vanilla JavaScript instead of JQuery. This is the function:

```
function submitForm() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(thisForm) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (thisForm.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        thisForm.classList.add('was-validated');
        <?php if(isset($shipping)){
            echo "stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the user if there was an error
                } else {
                    thisForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
                    // Send the token to the server
                    console.log('Sending token ' + result.token + '.');
                }
            });";
        }?>
    });
};
```

The form is created like this:

```
<form id="payment-form" onsubmit="return submitForm()" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

When I test the page with the form filled out correctly, double clicking the submit button prints the "Sending token" message to the console twice when it should only happen once. I thought maybe it was because it was taking too long to get to the part of the function where the form is disabled, but the message prints again no matter how many times the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

You're not calling the validation function with the `event` of when the form was clicked - and then you reference `event.preventDefault();`, but `event` is not defined.

Try something like this instead. Remove the `onsubmit` attribute, and do:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')].forEach((thisForm) => {
  thisForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => { // add the event argument here
    event.preventDefault();
    if (thisForm.checkValidity() === false) {
      // rest of your code
```

(though, I don't see why you're using `.filter` in the first place it doesn't make sense here - did you mean to use forEach? And if there's only one `#payment-form`, couldn't you have selected that by itself?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I implemented this and then realized I also had to remove the new top-level event listener created on the second line of your code. Very helpful, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To stop a form from submitting you should call `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;`

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit"></form>

handlesubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // or return false;
}
```